# Slash Commands "unknown interaction"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, handler

it was a silly error ( " } " in the wrong position ), whoever is interested in this handler I upgraded to v13 is very simple but it works well with it.

https://github.com/Inkeee/Tutorial-Discord-Bot

Well, I was trying to learn about slash commands, and in the meantime I did a handler based on some videos, and github, but when executing a slash command the error is thrown x times the number of existing commands.  (There are 3 commands, if I use a command the console receives 2 errors)

I suppose the bot is trying to execute all commands, but I don't know exactly what it is, or why!

my code:

```js
const { fs, Discord, erros, colors, emojis, database } = require('../../exports.js');

const slash = [];

const arquivos = fs.readdirSync("./src/slash").filter((file) =>
    file.endsWith(".js"))
    
module.exports = async (client) => {
  
  for (const files of arquivos) {
    
        const file = require(`../../slash/${files}`);
      
        slash.push(file);
      client.api.applications(client.user.id).commands.post({data: file.data})
    }

    client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', async (i) => {
        
        const command = slash.find(cmd => cmd.data.name === i.data.name.toLowerCase())
       
        if(command) command.execute(client, send, i);
     
      })
     
      async function send(interaction, content) {
        return client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
          data: {
                type: 4,
                data: await msg(interaction, content),
            },
        });
    }

     
      async function msg(i, c) {
        const m = await Discord.APIMessage.create(client.channels.resolve(i.channel_id), c)
          .resolveData()
          .resolveFiles();

        return { ...m.data, files: m.files }
      }
      
}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "ready",
  title: "Comandos slashs"
}
```

the event handlers get normal, the only problem is in the send function, in command

```js
const { Discord, erros, colors, emojis, database, titles} = require('../exports.js');

module.exports = {
  data: {
    name: "say",
    description: "Faça o bot falar",
      options: [{
        name: "text", 
        description: "texto que vai na mensagem",
        type: 3,
        required: true
      }]
  },
  async execute (client, send, i) {
    
    var args = i.data.options
    
    var texto = args.find(args => args.name.toLowerCase() === "text").value;
     
    await send(i, texto)
    
  }
}
```

Err:

````
(node:84) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown interaction at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner /Shinobu/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/R equestHandler.js:154:13) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/ process/task_queues.js:97:5) at async RequestHandler.push ner/Shinobu/node_modules/discord.js/src/res t/RequestHandler.js:39:14) at Object.execute (/home/runner/S hinobu/src/slash/say.js:20:5) ```
````

Comment: `client.api` is for private reasons. Support for that will not be provided.

Answer (score 37):

When you are using the slash commands you have 3 seconds to response.

To solve this using the latest discordjs (13.0.1) you can follow these solutions which will give you 15 mins.

**Solution 1:** Differ the reply and then edit it.

```
  await interaction.deferReply();
  const result = await YOUR_FUNCTION();
  await interaction.editReply(result);
```

**Solution 2:** Reply and then edit it.

```
  await interaction.reply('Working on it');
  const result = await YOUR_FUNCTION();
  await interaction.editReply(result);
```

**Solution 3:** Reply and then response with a follow up.

```
  await interaction.reply('Working on it');
  const result = await YOUR_FUNCTION();
  await interaction.followUp(result);
```

---

[You can find more information here!](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#deferred-responses)

Comment: The question was on v12

Comment: Then could you update your question with the version number? Since there is a lot of changes between discordjs versions this will make any answer invalid to you. Yet as mentioned above you have 3 seconds to response regardless of discordjs version. PS: I suggest updating to the latest version v13 which has the support to slash commands without using `client.api`. [This link can help you upgrading](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#before-you-start) as @radnerus commented: "`client.api` is for private reasons. Support for that will not be provided."

Comment: seriously, v13 released these days, obviously it was v12, and I've solved it myself.

Comment: Happy to hear that. It would be nice to share your solution as it will help anyone visit this question. Thank you :)

Comment: if I'm not mistaken it was just a } in the wrong position, and it made the intercessions try to be sent along with the for

Comment: The provided link it outdated here is the new [link](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#deferred-responses).

Answer (score 2):

This can be 2 things:

1. Your bot is taking too long to respond (pretty sure it has a 3 min limit or something)
2. It just does that sometimes. I have it working but with buttons and slash commands, and it works 99% of the time and sometimes it just does that.

Btw, I can't find anything wrong with your code so you should be good on that front.

Comment: Alternatively, you may need to just deploy your commands using a deploy script provided in discord getting started guide: https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/creating-commands.html#registering-commands